# DataTable and ODBC adapter

Tags: c#, odbc

I need to fill DataTable from ODBC Data adapter. I can see that dataTable is still empty but DataSet (ds) is successfully filled with data though.

```
OdbcConnection cnn;
                cnn = new OdbcConnection(azureConnection);
                using (OdbcCommand command = cnn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "{call sp_Get_Excel_Data(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", startTime);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", endTime);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rptSymbol", tickerSymbol);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", RegId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@events", events);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);

                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                    cnn.Open();

                    //DataTable
                    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    //DataSet
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    string[] colNames = new string[dataTable.Columns.Count];
                    int col = 0;

                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dataTable.Columns)
                        colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;
                }
```

Can you suggest why I can't see data in DataTable and how to make it work?

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue by casting to DataTable:
DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the issue by casting to DataTable:

```
DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove

```
adapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

And put **after filling ds**

```
dataTable = ds.Tables[0]
```

Or

```
dataTable = ds.Tables["name_of_your_table"]
```